# What does output of Convolutional neural network implies

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

Beginner to machine learning...
I know CNN model indicates value "1" for the class to which image belongs, otherwise "0". But the output I'm getting for one of my model is little weird.

Output-:
[[  1.00000000e+00 ,  1.02304026e-20  ,  0.00000000e+00]]

I observed the value of class 1 is higher as compare to other classes because the image I'm testing actually belongs to that class. But i really cant understand what that output implies and why it is not simply in 0 or 1.

Comment: CNN models don't indicate nothing. You do. CNN can produce lots of things depending on your problem and architecture (probabilities, arrays, booleans...).  You should read about the theory first !

Comment: your ouput is basically [1,0,0] indicating the your image has a 100% chance of belonging to class 1, and a (near) zero percent chance of belonging to class 2 and 3

Comment: but yes, @MohamedALANI is right.  Understand the theory first. Also, don't start with CNNs, start with a simple perceptron, then move to multi-layer perceptron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CNN is a type of neural network that is used the process images. What you are presenting is likely the output of a **classifier** that uses a CNN to process inputs. You observe that output because we often apply a [softmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) operation to the output vectors to produce a *probability distribution*, each value is between 0 and 1 and the vector sums to 1. Each entry in the output tells you the probability of the input belonging to a particular class. This is not the end of the story though, just a starting point for you.

The reason you observe very small number instead of 0 in the second entry is because these probabilities are based on the [logistic sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) which saturates towards 1 if input is large and 0 otherwise. When you use floating point numbers they get really close to 0 and 1 but do not necessarily become 1 or 0.